# Identityserver4: endpoint authentication client + user credentials

Tags: c#, identityserver4, openid-connect

I have an application running on this following structure:
[image]

My `Actor` is PKCE SPA application holding an access token, made with IdentityServer 4 redirection flow. My Frontend website allow this access token. Some of the Frontend website operation is calling the API server logics.

Right now I have an endpoint in the API server that requires the caller to be Frontend website client. But, I also want require a user content, the Actor in this case, which represent the user asking for the server.

Is it possible to supply two access token (one for the OpenId client, other for the customer)? Or I miss a better solution?

Comment: Depending on your grant type, IdentityServer4 already provides you with two tokens, an access_token and a id_token. Use auth code grant type.

Comment: @GHDevOps as far as I know, only the `Actor` (which PKCE client) is getting two tokens (access_token+id_token). The `Frontend website` client can do this too?

Comment: Yeah, but you'll need to do a silent login with the javascript oidc client